# Visualizations menu is gone, can't find it on the right hand side of my dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I can only see the visualizations menu on the top of the Power BI app, but I can't see it on the right hand side where it usually is. How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable on object interaction in the preview settings and it will return to how it was.

[image]